# Build error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'. styles_base.xml

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

I don't know what I did to break my build, probably an SDK upgrade, but in any case, I'm getting the above error when I rebuild my app.

I tried all the answers given on SO for the same problem, but nothing helped. Here are some details:

In the Android manifest:

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

I set the project build target to Android 6.0 and imported android-support-v7-appcompat and included it in the project:

[image: EclipseBuildError]

[image]

I've spent over two days on this and have run out of ideas.

UPDATE: The problem seems to be due to android-v7-appcompat.jar not getting placed in the /bin directory. I tried copying it from /libs to /bin, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the problem by installing a newer version of Eclipse (Mars), re-installing the Android SDK and importing my project from a backup. Builds fine now.